# Aws LEX How to setup dynamic list options for a slot specific to a session

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am building a aws lex bot., where user can choose his funding source. I would like to provide the user with list of his funding sources. Since each user has different funding sources.
The question is there's a slot called "fundingSource" which can have a list specific to the user.
Possible values for this slot is user-specific.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *actually* create a slot with dynamic values. But you can make it appear that way to the user.

I suggest you build a general custom slotType with every possible value in your list and use that slot for every user.

Then in your Lambda function, you can cross-reference the user ID with your data on which values are actually available to that user. Then allow or disallow the user to select that option.

I would also perform this database search before eliciting the slot. That way, I can present the user with a customized dynamic list inside of the elicit slot question and at least guide the user to choose one that is allowed.

For example:

> Let's say the slotType is named `FundingSources` and it has the complete list of sources possible to all users. Let's say they are named `A,B,C,D,...Z`.
> Next, we create a slot for this intent called `FundingSource` and use the above slotType.
> Then, we build the Lambda code to detect and recognize a user by the user ID when they initiate a conversation with the bot. Then we retrieve the user's specific list of funding sources from our database. Let's say this user has funding sources: `A, D, X`.
> We can save that data in `sessionAttributes` until we require it in the conversation. Then when we need to ask about which source they want, we can build the ElicitSlot question to ask, `"Would you like to use A, D, or X, as your funding source?"`

> The user will 90% of the time reply with one of those options. But let's say they reply with value `B`. This will then be double-checked in Lambda and caught as not one of their possible values for this slot. We reset the value to null and re-elicit the same slot with a new custom question: `Sorry, but the funding sources available are A, D, or X. Which would you like?`
> Or maybe you'd like to offer them other options at this point for acquiring `B` as a funding source. Now that's possible and your bot appears to be highly intelligent with a dynamic slot.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I Don't think this solution works for my scenario.
I will look for an alternative. Thank you :)

Comment: Well, another option is using ConfirmIntent which has a built-in Yes/No detection. But even though it is supposed to be used to confirm completion of an intent, you can use it for individual slots. It's just more difficult in Lambda to catch the response and build the logic around it.